Connecting to network even when it not broadcasting its SSID name on Windows 10
I wanted to check up in advanced network settings if "Connect to network even when its not broadcasting its SSID" option is checked. In windows 11 it is easy to find option in advanced network settings, but on windows 10, I was not able to find that option.
Any advice or tutorial how to find it?

You can change it in the Network and Sharing Centre. To get there, either:

Open Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Centre
Open Settings > Network & Internet > Wifi/Ethernet > Network and Sharing Centre in the right side bar.

Then select your network, open "Wireless Properties" and there it is.
